# Comparing an Object's values with compareTo()

Tags: java, heap, comparable, compareto

I am using a Max-Heap to store objects of type `Song`. A song has a title and a rating as shown in the `Song` class. I want the `Song` object to be compared by rating so that the highest rated songs are displayed first. If songs have the same rating then they should be compared by alphabetical order of title. What I have now is currently outputting it by highest rating, but incorrectly.

Heap:

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private ArrayList<T> heap;

public Heap(){
    heap = new ArrayList<T>();
}
public int getPLoc(int i){
    return (i - 1) / 2;
}
public int getLCLoc(int i){
    return 2 * i + 1;
}
public int getRCLoc(int i){
    return 2 * i + 2;
}
public T getNodeAt(int i) {
    if(heap.get(i) == null) {
        System.out.println("Item does not exist.");
        return null;
    }else {
        return heap.get(i);
    }
}
public void addNode(T n) {
    heap.add(null);
    int index = heap.size() - 1;
    while(index > 0 && (getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)).compareTo(n)) < 0) { //Is this correct?
        heap.set(index, getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)));
        index = getPLoc(index);
    }
    heap.set(index, n);
}
```

Song:

```
public class Song implements Comparable<Song> {
private String title;
private String rating;

public Song(String t, String r) {
    title = t;
    rating = r;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getRating(){
    return rating;
}
// Need help here adding it to also compare by alphabetical title if songs have same ratings.
public int compareTo(Song s) {
    return rating.compareTo(s.getRating());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method returns an `int` with the following values:

**negative** If `thisObject < anotherObject`

**zero** If `thisObject == anotherObject`

**positive** If `thisObject > anotherObject`

`Check for value zero`, meaning rating is same, then go for `title comparison`.

**Sample Code , can be tweaked**

```
public int compareTo(Song s) {
    int val = rating.compareTo(s.getRating());
      if(val == 0){
         val = title.compareTo(s.getTitle());
      }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to compare the name of the songs if their Rank is equal (and compareTo therefore returns 0) and return the result of the Second compare